# Asp.Net Web API vs Web Services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have several sites that use standard web services with results returned as Json to JQuery ajax calls. These sites use none of the standard .Net controls or view state, they are all done using html5 and JQuery. Example: http://ReactiveWebDesign.Net

I started playing with the new Web API, but I'm also trying to figure out what (if anything) I am gaining if I make the switch and start using to the new Web API.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs clarity/refinement - what are you really asking?

- If you are asking if you "must" use controls to consume web services in ASP.Net. Answer: of course not. Controls and/or helpers are provided to you if you want to cobble things up quickly, aka "set and forget" - but that doesn't mean you can't go "bare metal" if you so choose.
- ASP.Net is a technology that encompasses web services, web forms, mvc/razor, data, script, etc. You are free to choose which components to use, mix and match, and do as you please. You can write HTML5, use jQuery, consume/use web services of your own or 3rd parties with or without using "controls" or mix/match as you please.
- You can build your own web services in ASP.Net or .Net/WCF, consume them and/or make them available externally.

---

Update:

As with every iteration of ASP.Net, Microsoft makes things *easier*. If you are looking to create a web service, the new "Web API" makes things easier as shown in this [sample](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

I can personally say that the Web API sample "looks" just like a normal MVC project that ASP.Net developers already know - as opposed to say WCF where "proper configuration" is ever present to successful deployment (e.g. behavior settings, endpoints, etc.).

IMHO, *ease* is probably the best reason to start using Web API.

Comment: EdSF... The question is really nothing more than what am I gaining by using the Web API instead of Web Services on a website. I do know that I don't need to use any Asp.Net features as all the web services are being consumed by JQuery and the results being placed in standard html controls.

Answer (score 0):

basically, you can get a lot of benifits, such as RESTful api, the ability of running out of IIS(Self-Host), improved IoC support and so on..
for more details please visit: http://www.asp.net/web-api